# Перегрузка "=" для private элемента

Tags: c++

```
class A
{
private:
  int x;
};
```

Нужно перегрузить оператор `=` для `x`, хоть это и стандартный тип. КАК?!

Comment: желательно без препроцесара

Comment: Совершенно не понятно, что вы собираетесь перегрузить.

Comment: опеееееератор =

Comment: надо чтобы x= выполняло определеные дествия

Comment: Покажите, какой код вы хотите написать, и как он должен работать. То есть желаемый синтаксис и семантику.

Comment: x=5
и должно не только присвоить но и ещё делать действия другие

Comment: для приват полей можно както

Comment: @IGOR: В такой формулировке ответ «нет, невозможно».

Comment: как так то? а если свой класс запилить в нем сделать а потом опять в int переконвертить?

Comment: хотя бы тааааак

Comment: Тогда конкретизируйте, какое у вас условие. Что можно менять, что нельзя. А то если `x` поменять на `y`, `=` на `+`, а `5` на `"привет"`, то да, может много чего произойти. Но это **не называется** словом «перегрузить».

Comment: надо короче x=5, чтобы делало определенные действия, можно всё

Comment: Если мы сделаем класс x, ошибка будет?

Comment: Что означает «можно всё»? `#define x system("rm -rf /")` можно?

Comment: я ж сказал желательно без препроцесора

Comment: Тогда ещё раз: уточните, что конкретно можно. Без этого вопрос не имеет смысла. Может, можно дописать после икса скобки, мало ли что у вас можно.

Comment: всё остальное кроме препроцессора

Comment: Скобки после икса дописать можно? Поле типа `int` с именем `x` в классе обязано быть или нет? Где должен находиться вызов — в функции `main` можно?

Comment: ну всё это показано в условии
int x;
x= без скобок
main - неважно

Comment: со скобками любой може

Comment: НИКТО НЕ ЗНАЕТ ППЦ

Comment: `x` обязан ссылаться именно на поле `x` класса `A`? Или можно написать так: `int main() { B x; x = 5; }`?

Comment: ну а как еще ээ

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32091/discussion-on-question-by-igor---private-).

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете перегружать операторы только для пользовательский типов: классов, объединений, перечислений. Вы не можете перегрузить оператор присваивания для целых чисел.

Или более точно (C++ стандарт, 13.5 Overloaded operators )

> 6 An operator function shall either be a non-static member function or
>   be a non-member function and have at least one parameter whose type is
>   a class, a reference to a class, an enumeration, or a reference to an
>   enumeration.

Например, можно перегрузить оператор присваивания для класса из вашего примера, когда объекту класса присваивается целочисленное значение.

```
class A
{
private:
    int x;
public:
    A & operator =( int x )
    {
        A::x = x;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Comment: нужно перегрузить, несмотря на то тчо int я как бы про это написал

Comment: раз задали такое значит можно

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос довольно путаный, рискну предположить, что нужно что-то вроде:

testc.h:

```
class Testc
{
public:
    Testc() { x = 0 ;}
    Testc(int x) : x(x) {}
    Testc & operator=(const Testc &rhs); // присваивание объекту другого объекта
    Testc & operator=(int x); // присваивание объекту целого числа
    int& value() { return x; }
private:
    int x;
};
```

testc.cpp:

```
#include "testc.h"

Testc& Testc::operator =(const Testc &rhs) {
    if (this != &rhs) {
        this->x = rhs.x;
    }
    return *this;
}

Testc& Testc::operator =(int x) {
    this->x = x;
    return *this;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Testc t1(4);
    t1.value() = 5;
    std::cout << t1.value() << std::endl;
}
```

Можно, конечно, реализовать и такое: `t1.x() = 5`
Замените в коде `int x` на `int m_x`, `value()` на `x()` - профит.

Comment: а прокоментить можна?

Comment: t1.x() = 5 !!!!!

Comment: Если что-то непонятно в коде, то это уже к книжкам, код тривиальный, на уровне самых базовых знаний. Вот `t1.x() = 5` будет сложнее немного.

Comment: так он и нада!!!

Comment: сорри, это уже не сейчас. Либо позже, либо завтра.

Comment: Не, все не так сложно...